# The PHP crawler I am using has a memory leak, what is causing this?

Tags: php, memory-leaks, web-crawler

I am using a PHP crawler that has a memory leak. It is good for the first ~3125 links, then it runs out of memory.I tried getting rid of the MySQL insert, but that did not change anything. Can someone help me diagnose this problem? Thank you so much.

```
<?php
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php';
ini_set('max_execution_time', 0);
// USAGE
$startURL = $your_url;
$depth = 9999;
$crawler = new crawler($startURL, $depth);
// Exclude path with the following structure to be processed 
$crawler->addFilterPath('customer/account/login/referer');
$crawler->run();
class crawler
{
protected $_url;
protected $_depth;
protected $_host;
protected $_seen = array();
protected $_filter = array();

public function __construct($url, $depth = 5)
{
    $this->_url = $url;
    $this->_depth = $depth;
    $parse = parse_url($url);
    $this->_host = $parse['host'];
}

protected function _processAnchors($content, $url, $depth)
{
    $dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
    @$dom->loadHTML($content);
    $anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

    foreach ($anchors as $element) {
        $href = $element->getAttribute('href');
        if (0 !== strpos($href, 'http')) {
            $path = '/' . ltrim($href, '/');
            if (extension_loaded('http')) {
                $href = http_build_url($url, array('path' => $path));
            } else {
                $parts = parse_url($url);
                $href = $parts['scheme'] . '://';
                if (isset($parts['user']) && isset($parts['pass'])) {
                    $href .= $parts['user'] . ':' . $parts['pass'] . '@';
                }
                $href .= $parts['host'];
                if (isset($parts['port'])) {
                    $href .= ':' . $parts['port'];
                }
                $href .= $path;
            }
        }
        // Crawl only link that belongs to the start domain
        $this->crawl_page($href, $depth - 1);
    }
}


protected function _getContent($url)
{
    $handle = curl_init($url);


    curl_setopt($handle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);


    $response = curl_exec($handle);

    curl_close($handle);
    return array($response);
}

protected function _printResult($url, $depth)
{
    ob_end_flush();
    $currentDepth = $this->_depth - $depth;
    $count = count($this->_seen);
    echo "$url <br>";
    include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php';
    $databaseconnect = new  PDO("mysql:dbname=DB_NAME;host=$mysqlhost;charset=utf8", $mysqlusername, $mysqlpassword); 
    $statement = $databaseconnect->prepare("INSERT INTO data(url,name) VALUES(:url,:name)");
    $statement->execute(array(':url' => $url,
    ':name' => $url));
    ob_start();
    flush();
}

protected function isValid($url, $depth)
{
    if (strpos($url, $this->_host) === false
        || $depth === 0
        || isset($this->_seen[$url])
    ) {
        return false;
    }
    foreach ($this->_filter as $excludePath) {
        if (strpos($url, $excludePath) !== false) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public function crawl_page($url, $depth)
{
    if (!$this->isValid($url, $depth)) {
        return;
    }
    // add to the seen URL
    $this->_seen[$url] = true;
    // get Content and Return Code
    list($content) = $this->_getContent($url);
    // print Result for current Page
    $this->_printResult($url, $depth);
    // process subPages
    $this->_processAnchors($content, $url, $depth);
}

public function addFilterPath($path)
{
    $this->_filter[] = $path;
}

public function run()
{
    $this->crawl_page($this->_url
    , $this->_depth);
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this classifies as a memory leak exactly. You are essentially using recursion without a terminating case. Before the crawl_page() method finishes it calls _processAnchors(), which in turn may call crawl_page() again if it finds any links (very likely). Every recursive call eats up more memory because the originating crawl_page() call (and most thereafter) can't be removed from the call stack until all of its recursive calls terminate.